# About real time statistics oracle 19c only for particular table

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-12c, oracle-19c

Reg Real-Time statistics which extends online statistics gathering(12c) to also include conventional DML statements.
Real-time statistics helps the optimizer generate more optimal plans.Whereas bulk load operations gather all necessary statistics, real-time statistics augment rather than replace traditional statistics.

Oracle introduced new parameters

`_optimizer_gather_stats_on_conventional_dml` and `_optimizer_use_stats_on_conventional_dml` which are true by default and
`_optimizer_stats_on_conventional_dml_sample_rate` at 100%

How does real time statistics works?

By default the `_optimizer_gather_stats_on_conventional_dml` is true so its automatically kicks off

When a DML operation is currently modifying a table (conventional), Oracle Database dynamically computes values for the most essential statistics if the above parameter is on.

Consider a example of table that is having lot of inserts and rows are increasing. Real-time statistics keep track of the increasing row count as rows are being inserted. If the optimizer performs a hard parse of a new query, then the optimizer can use the real-time statistics to obtain a more accurate cost estimate.

`USER_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` and `USER_TAB_STATISITICS` has columns NOTES tell real time statistics have been used. "STATS_ON_CONVENTIONAL_DML".

Execution Plan shows

```
|Id| Operation                        | Name|Rows|Bytes|Cost (%CPU)|Time| Pstart|Pstop|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0| INSERT STATEMENT                 |     |    |     |910 (100)|        |     |     |
| 1|  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL         |SALES|    |     |         |        |     |     |
| 2|   OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |     |918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|     |     |
| 3|    PARTITION RANGE ALL           |     |918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|   1 |  28 |
| 4|     TABLE ACCESS FULL            |SALES|918K|  25M|910   (2)|00:00:01|   1 |  28 |

Also the explain plan in the query used will tell in note section
    Note

    -----
    - dynamic statistics used: stats for conventional DML
```

`LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL` and `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` are the new parameters that have been added to the explain plan for this new feature.

`can we apply real-time statistics only for a particular set of table . if yes, how can we achieve them ? , as we know getting real time statistics for any dml operation thats occuring for more that 100k rows is very costly operation`

I tried finding out the way, but was not successfull

Comment: Be careful in wanting to know exactly how any parameters beginning with an underscore "`_`" as those are un-documented, and subject to change; so even if you could figure out how they currently work, it could change, or they could have bugs.  If you encounter a performance issue where you have changed those parameters, the first thing Oracle Support will ask you to do is to un-set those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you should only change underscore parameters when instructed to do so by support. But more importantly for these parameters, Real-Time Statistics is only available on specific database offerings. See the [license guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-F796455D-C7EF-4836-9F69-2BCCDA49B7BD) for details.

***Changing these parameters is likely to be a violation of your license agreement!***

> `LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL` and `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` are the new
>   parameters that have been added to the explain plan for this new
>   feature.

These operations are not specific to Real-Time Statistics. `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` is for any operation that captures stats during execution. `create table as select` is an example that has done this for a while now.

`LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL` means the database does a conventional (not direct-path) insert.

You can disable Real-Time Statistics for:

- A specific statement with the `no_gather_optimizer_statistics` hint
- A table by locking stats for that table (though this will stop the background job gathering stats too!)

For example, only the first of these three inserts has the `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` operation:

```
set long 10000
set serveroutput off
cl scr
create table t as 
  select 1 c1 from dual
  connect by level <= 100;

insert /*+ monitor */into t 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select * from rws;

select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor (report_level=> 'basic +plan')
from   dual;

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=2403765415)
======================================================================================================================================================
| Id |             Operation             | Name |  Rows   | Cost |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Read | Read  | Activity | Activity Detail |
|    |                                   |      | (Estim) |      | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) | Reqs | Bytes |   (%)    |   (# samples)   |
======================================================================================================================================================
|  0 | INSERT STATEMENT                  |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |      |       |          |                 |
|  1 |   LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL         | T    |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |    4 | 32768 |          |                 |
|  2 |    OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |      |       |          |                 |
|  3 |     VIEW                          |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |      |       |          |                 |
|  4 |      CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |      |       |          |                 |
|  5 |       FAST DUAL                   |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        1 |      |       |          |                 |
======================================================================================================================================================    

insert /*+ monitor no_gather_optimizer_statistics */ into t 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select * from rws;

select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor (report_level=> 'basic +plan')
from   dual;

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=2403765415)
======================================================================================================================================
| Id |            Operation             | Name |  Rows   | Cost |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Activity | Activity Detail |
|    |                                  |      | (Estim) |      | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) |   (%)    |   (# samples)   |
======================================================================================================================================
|  0 | INSERT STATEMENT                 |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |          |                 |
|  1 |   LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL        | T    |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |          |                 |
|  2 |    VIEW                          |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |          |                 |
|  3 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |          |                 |
|  4 |      FAST DUAL                   |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        1 |          |                 |
======================================================================================================================================    

exec dbms_stats.lock_table_stats ( user, 'T' );

insert /*+ monitor */into t 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select * from rws;

select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor (report_level=> 'basic +plan')
from   dual;

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=2403765415)
======================================================================================================================================
| Id |            Operation             | Name |  Rows   | Cost |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Activity | Activity Detail |
|    |                                  |      | (Estim) |      | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) |   (%)    |   (# samples)   |
======================================================================================================================================
|  0 | INSERT STATEMENT                 |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |          |                 |
|  1 |   LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL        | T    |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        0 |          |                 |
|  2 |    VIEW                          |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |          |                 |
|  3 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING |      |         |      |         1 |     +0 |     1 |       10 |          |                 |
|  4 |      FAST DUAL                   |      |       1 |    2 |         1 |     +0 |     1 |        1 |          |                 |
======================================================================================================================================
```

> as we know getting real time statistics for any dml operation thats
>   occuring for more that 100k rows is very costly operation

How do you know this?